# The notorious yet unaswered issue of downloading a file when windows security is required

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, webbrowser-control, webclient

There is a web site: http://site.domain.com which prompts for credentials with "windows security" dialog box. So I managed to use WebBrowser control to navigate to the page and send keystrokes to enter the password - I could not find another way around.

Now I came to the point where the website generates a link to a file I want to download, it looks like: http://site.domain.com/operations/reporting/csv/Report720_2553217.csv

I tried to use WebClient to download the file but it does nothing (br is my WebBrowser control):

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
wb.Headers.Add( br.Document.Cookie);
wb.DownloadFile(link, @"report.csv");
```

I have been trying to find a working solution to no avail. I know the web client is not authenticated so tried to use web browser's cookie but it does not work. The cookie looks as follows:

TLTUID=61FE48D8F9B910F9E930F42D6A03EAA6; TLTSID=0B2B8EE82688102641B7E768807FA8B2; s_cc=true; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; ASPSESSIONIDQQSTRDQS=FNPJCODCEMGFIDHFLKDBEMHO

So I have two questions:

1. How to allow web client to download a file accessible from web browser's session. What am I doing wrong in the above code sample?
2. Is there an easy way to use WebBrowser solely to download and save that file to the path and filename of my choice? Or how to do it all using WebClient or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not possible, AFAIK. `WebClient` and `WebBrowser` use different layers to access web. `WebClient` uses [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `WebBrowser` uses  [UrlMon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee318402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Thus, they would have separate sessions (including the authentication cache).
2. That's possible, just use any of [UrlMon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee318402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs to download the file, e.g. `URLDownloadToFile` or `URLDownloadToCacheFile`. I've just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18995830/1768303).

On a side note, you don't have to feed in keystrokes to provide authentication credentials. You can implement [IAuthenticateEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on `WebBrowser` site object for this. Here is [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18619110/1768303).

Comment: I have urlmon.dll library on my PC but cannot reference it. I am building a console application in MS Visual 2010 targeting .NET 4. What am I missing here?

Comment: You do not reference it, it's not a COM DLL. Rather, you declare `URLDownloadToFile` in your class as p/invoke method, here's a complete example: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/URLDownloadToFile%20.html

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.
When it's done I'll post the full code so that other people have a full picture of the solution.

Comment: As to IAuthenticateEx, I had a look at the suggested articles but again I do not know where to start as the interface/method is not recognized. Do I need to import/declare a specific external library too?

Comment: I don't have an example of implementing this in C#, you'd need to define the interface yourself. You could take this [IAuthenticate](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IAuthenticate.html) as a base. Alternatively, implementing `IAuthenticate` might be just enough for you case, if there's only one authentication dialog. On the bright side, Poggy (the person who asked the question) has apparently [succeeded](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18615164/1768303), using those links.

Answer (score 2):

So this is the working solution which meets the requirements given in my question. It automatically navigates to the specified website, authenticates and downloads a generated report. I used [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149259/webbrowser-control-autheticate-not-working-when-access-file-folder) as an outline.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;

using System.Security.Authentication;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Policy;



namespace margot_report
{



    [ComImport,
Guid("00000112-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IOleObject
    {
        void SetClientSite(IOleClientSite pClientSite);

    }


    [ComImport,
Guid("00000118-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IOleClientSite
    {
        void SaveObject();
        void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk);
        void GetContainer(object ppContainer);
        void ShowObject();
        void OnShowWindow(bool fShow);
        void RequestNewObjectLayout();
    }

    [ComImport,
    GuidAttribute("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa"),
    InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
    ComVisible(false)]
    public interface IServiceProvider
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr
        ppvObject);
    }




    [ComImport]
    [Guid("79EAC9D0-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IAuthenticate
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Authenticate(IntPtr phwnd,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] ref string pszUsername,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] ref string pszPassword);
    }




    class SelfAuthenticatingWebBrowser : WebBrowser, IOleClientSite, IAuthenticate, IServiceProvider
    {
        public static Guid IID_IAuthenticate = new Guid("79eac9d0-baf9-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b");
        public static Guid SID_IAuthenticate = new Guid("79eac9d0-baf9-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b");
        public const int INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION = unchecked((int)0x800C0011);
        public const int S_OK = unchecked((int)0x00000000);






        public void Authenticate(IntPtr phwnd, ref string pszUsername, ref string pszPassword)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Authenticate");

            pszUsername = Program.username; //
            pszPassword = Program.password; // 
            //return S_OK;

        }

        public int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("QueryService");
            int nRet = guidService.CompareTo(IID_IAuthenticate); // Zero returned if the compared objects are equal
            if (nRet == 0)
            {
                nRet = riid.CompareTo(IID_IAuthenticate); // Zero returned if the compared objects are equal
                if (nRet == 0)
                {
                    ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this,
                    typeof(IAuthenticate));
                    return S_OK;
                }
            }
            ppvObject = new IntPtr();
            return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION;
        }

        public void SaveObject()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void GetContainer(object ppContainer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ShowObject()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnShowWindow(bool fShow)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void RequestNewObjectLayout()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

public IComponent  Component
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public IContainer  Container
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public bool  DesignMode
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public string  Name
{
      get 
    { 
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }
      set 
    { 
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }
}


}



    class Program 
    {

        static bool send = true, verbose=false, clicked=false, submitted=false;
        static int c = 0, t=0;
        public static string filename, report, username, password;

        /// <summary>
/// The URLMON library contains this function, URLDownloadToFile, which is a way
/// to download files without user prompts.  The ExecWB( _SAVEAS ) function always
/// prompts the user, even if _DONTPROMPTUSER parameter is specified, for "internet
/// security reasons".  This function gets around those reasons.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pCaller">Pointer to caller object (AX).</param>
/// <param name="szURL">String of the URL.</param>
/// <param name="szFileName">String of the destination filename/path.</param>
/// <param name="dwReserved">[reserved].</param>
/// <param name="lpfnCB">A callback function to monitor progress or abort.</param>
/// <returns>0 for okay.</returns>
[DllImport("URLMON.DLL", EntryPoint = "URLDownloadToFileW", SetLastError = true,
         CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,
         CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int URLDownloadToFile(int pCaller, string srcURL,
    string dstFile, int Reserved, int CallBack);




        static void Main(string[] args)
        {




//            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://site.domain.com/operations/reporting/report-run.asp?reportid=720");
////webRequest.Proxy = webProxy;

           string appname = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];

             if (args.Count() < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type: \"{0}\" -h for help on usage.\n", appname);
                return;
            }

            if (args.Count() > 0)
                foreach (var s in args)
                    if (s.Contains("-h") || s.Contains("/h") || s.Contains("-?") || s.Contains("/?"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nUsage: {0} [-rfupv] <values>\n", appname);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n -r report_link ");
                        Console.WriteLine(" -f output_file ");
                        Console.WriteLine(" -u username   ");
                        Console.WriteLine(" -p password   ");
                        Console.WriteLine(" -t time_delay - seconds to wait before sending key strokes");
                        Console.WriteLine(" -v                  verbose output to console (for debugging)");
                        Console.WriteLine(" -h|?                Display this info and exit.");

                        return;
                    }


            try
            {
                if (args.Any(x => x.Contains("-f")))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (!args[i].Contains("-f")) i++;
                    filename =args[i + 1];
                }
                else filename = "report.csv";

                if (args.Any(x => x.Contains("-r")))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (!args[i].Contains("-r")) i++;
                    report = args[i + 1];
                }
                else report = "http://site.domain.com/operations/reporting/report-run.asp?reportid=720";

                if (args.Any(x => x.Contains("-u")))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (!args[i].Contains("-u")) i++;
                    username = args[i + 1];
                }
                else username = "";

                 if (args.Any(x => x.Contains("-p")))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (!args[i].Contains("-p")) i++;
                    password = args[i + 1];
                }
                else password = "";

                 if (args.Any(x => x.Contains("-t")))
                 {
                     int i = 0;
                     while (!args[i].Contains("-t")) i++;
                     t = int.Parse(args[i + 1]);
                 }
                 else t = 5;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null) Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                return;
            }

            ///////////////////////////////

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            Console.WriteLine("start");
            var th = new Thread(() => {

            //WebBrowser 

                var wb = new SelfAuthenticatingWebBrowser();    // WebBrowser();



            wb.Show(); Console.WriteLine(wb.DocumentText);
            Console.WriteLine(wb.DocumentText);
            wb.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            wb.NewWindow += browser_newWindow; 
            wb.ControlAdded += browser_ControlAdded ;
            wb.LostFocus += browser_LostFocus;
            wb.Navigating += browser_Navigating;
            wb.FileDownload += browser_FileDownload;
            //wb.Site =  new MySitex();   
            //Console.WriteLine(wb.Site.GetService(typeof(IAuthenticateEx)));//wb.Site.Name

            Console.WriteLine(wb.AllowNavigation);
                wb.Navigate("about:blank");

                object obj = wb.ActiveXInstance;
                IOleObject oc = obj as IOleObject;
                oc.SetClientSite(wb as IOleClientSite);
                //this.Site = this as ISite;
                System.IntPtr ppvServiceProvider;
                IServiceProvider sp = wb as IServiceProvider;
                sp.QueryService(ref SelfAuthenticatingWebBrowser.SID_IAuthenticate, ref SelfAuthenticatingWebBrowser.IID_IAuthenticate, out ppvServiceProvider);               


            wb.Navigate(report);
                   Application.Run();
            });

            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("end");
        }


        static void browser_Navigating(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("navigating..." );
            var s = sender as WebBrowser;
            Console.WriteLine(s.DocumentTitle + s.Name);
            //foreach (var x in s.Controls)
            //    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            //foreach(Form x in Application.OpenForms)
            //    Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
            if (false)//(send)
            {
                send = false;
                var thekeys = new Thread(() =>
                {

                    Thread.Sleep(t*1000);

                    if (username != "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("sending username key strokes");
                        SendKeys.SendWait(username);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
                        Console.WriteLine("sent");
                    }

                    if (password != "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("sending password key strokes");
                        SendKeys.SendWait(password);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Console.WriteLine("sent");
                    }

                });
                thekeys.Start();
            }


        }

        static void browser_FileDownload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(verbose) Console.WriteLine("FileDownload : " + e.ToString());
            var s = sender as WebBrowser;
            if (verbose) Console.WriteLine(s.DocumentTitle + s.Name + s.Url); //Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void browser_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("lost focus : " + e.ToString());
            var s = sender as WebBrowser;
            Console.WriteLine(s.DocumentTitle + s.Name);
        }
        static void browser_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("control added : " + e.ToString());
            var s = sender as WebBrowser;
            Console.WriteLine(s.DocumentTitle + s.Name);
        }

        static void browser_newWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("new : " + e.ToString());
            var s = sender as WebBrowser;
            Console.WriteLine(s.DocumentTitle + s.Name);
        }

        static void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var br = sender as WebBrowser;
            if (e.Url.ToString()=="about:blank") return;

            if (br.Url == e.Url)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Navigated to {0}", e.Url);

                if (e.Url.ToString() == "http://site.domain.com/operations/reporting/report-generate.asp") submitted = true;
                if(verbose) Console.WriteLine(br.DocumentText);
                //Console.WriteLine(br.Document.Cookie);
                if(!clicked)
                foreach (HtmlElement x in br.Document.All)
                {
                   // if (x.All == null)

                    //Console.WriteLine("|{0} {1} {2}| [{3}]\n", x.Id, x.Name, ".",x.GetAttribute("value"));
                    if (x.Name == "format" && x.GetAttribute("value") == "C") { Console.WriteLine("\n C L I C K !\n"); x.InvokeMember("click"); Thread.Sleep(1000); clicked = true; }

                    //else foreach (HtmlElement y in x.Document.All)
                      //      Console.WriteLine("|{0} {1} {2}| [{3}]\n", y.Id, y.Name, y.OuterHtml, x.InnerText);
                }

                if (clicked && !submitted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("submitting the report");


                    if (verbose) Console.WriteLine(" function at: {0}", br.DocumentText.IndexOf("function runReport()"));
                    //var newtext = br.DocumentText.Replace("value=\"R\" checked", "value=\"R\" ").Replace("value=\"C\"", "value=\"C\" checked");
                    //Console.WriteLine(" function at: {0}", br.DocumentText.IndexOf("function runReport()"));

                    br.Document.InvokeScript("runReport");

                    Console.WriteLine("done");

                    //Console.WriteLine(br.DocumentText);

                }

                //if (c == 1)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(br.DocumentText);
                    if (verbose) Console.WriteLine(br.DocumentText.IndexOf("http://"));
                    if (verbose) Console.WriteLine(br.DocumentText.IndexOf(".csv"));

                }

                if (verbose) Console.WriteLine("c = {0}", c);

                //http://site.domain.com/operations/reporting/csv/Report714_4045373.csv
                if (submitted)
                {
                    int start = br.DocumentText.IndexOf("csv/Report");

                    int end = 0; if (start >= 0) end = br.DocumentText.IndexOf(".csv", start);

                    if (start > 0 && end > start)
                    {
                        if (verbose) Console.WriteLine(br.DocumentText.Substring(start, end - start));
                        string link = "http://site.domain.com/operations/reporting/" + br.DocumentText.Substring(start, end - start) + ".csv";
                        Console.WriteLine(link);

                        //Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
                        //Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

                        if (URLDownloadToFile(0, link, filename, 0, 0) == 0)
                            Console.WriteLine("The report has been saved as {0}", filename);
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("There was a problem with downloading/saving the report {0}", report);

                        Application.ExitThread();

                    }
                }
                if (verbose) Console.WriteLine("cookies ? {0}, {1}, {2}", br.Document.Cookie == null, br.Document.Cookie == "", br.Document.Cookie);
                c++;
                if(c>4) Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
            }
        }


    }


}
```