# Does Webkit show file save dialog on download? How to skip in WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, webkit, webbrowser-control

Hope you are doing good.

My requirement is to download some files from a site which requires login, password. I am able to navigate through all the way to the file generation page.(**using .Net webBrowser control**). I am stuck at file save dialog. I want to skip it but unable to do so as the there is no direct link to the file to be downloaded. A function is called and the file is created on the fly.

I am considering to use something else than **webBrowser**. Please guide me, if webkit also shows the same file dialog? **Is there a respectively easier way to skip that using webKit?**

I am using .Net 4.5 and windows 7 32 bit.

### **What i have already tried:**

```
SendKeys.WaitSend("{Enter}")
```

**Result:** Enter is sent to the webbrowser control, not to the file download dialog. I have tried to get the process of the file dialog. But Process "WindowsFormsApplication.vshost"** doesn't have any child processes.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadDataCompleted += new  DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);
client.DownloadDataAsync(e.Url);
```

**Result:**
e.URL has no direct link. On clicking the file for download, a function is called at back-end. I have seen in Firefox the code inside that function, which is just this one line:

```
document.location.href = 'something.do?something='+variable1+'&something='+variable2+ '&something=' + variable3;
```

Investigating above, i am able to call that function directly by pasting the following line in browser.(in case my session has not expired):

https://something.com/downloadsomething.do?somevariable=45875&somenumber=54875125&somevariable=1Hg5422

and what i see next is a dialog box asking save/open/cancel.

Thank You,
Regards

Comment: Webkit (atleast WebkitGTK) certainly supports not showing dialog - it all depnds upon how top level browser skin handles the events fired by core engine. I am using it to download the files without showing dialog. http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitDownload.html#webkit-download-set-destination. Sorry no idea about windows web browser control

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025793/1768303

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using pinvoke. By bringing the save dialog window to front and then sending keys to it.

```
IntPtr fileDownloadDialogPointer = FindWindow(null, "File Download");
SetForegroundWindow(fileDownloadDialogPointer);
SendKeys.SendWait("%s");
```

%s is for "Alt + S". After this, save as dialog will appear. Handling that too in the same way. 
Thank You ALL